# DrawingCore exception in azure function c# .net

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions

**Unhandled Exception: System.MemberAccessException**:

```
Object is busy and cannot state allow this operation [GDI+ status: ObjectBusy]
       at System.DrawingCore.GDIPlus.CheckStatus(Status status)
       at System.DrawingCore.Image.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
       at System.DrawingCore.Image.Finalize()
```

This error occurs once in a while for following code. I am using sautinsoft library and imageFormat is of System.DrawingCore.Imaging.

```
  using (Stream fs = pdfFile.OpenReadStream())
      {
        await Task.Run(() => _pdfFocus.OpenPdf(fs));
        if (_pdfFocus.PageCount > 0)
          {
            _pdfFocus.ImageOptions.ImageFormat = imageFormat;
            _pdfFocus.ImageOptions.Dpi = 100;
            _pdfFocus.ImageOptions.JpegQuality = 90;
            for (int i = 1; i <= _pdfFocus.PageCount; i++)
              {
                 await Task.Run(() => pdfPagesAsImageFileList.Add(_pdfFocus.ToImage(i)));
              }
            }
         Task.WaitAll();
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Marc said the azure has sandbox limitations, and mostly .net package to convert pdf to image need GDI and this is not supported. For now I only find one package to iplement it with .net. You could try with [GhostScript](https://ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) and [Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET#the-net-library-for-imagemagick-magicknet) to implement it.

After installing the `Ghostscript`, you will get the `gsdll32.dll` file in the bin folder. The below is my test code, copy the 02.pdf and **gsdll32.dll** to the kudu `wwwroot` folder.

```
using System.Net.Http;
using ImageMagick;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;

namespace FunctionApp6
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log,ExecutionContext context)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            MagickNET.SetGhostscriptDirectory(context.FunctionAppDirectory);
            log.Info(context.FunctionAppDirectory);
            MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
            // Settings the density to 300 dpi will create an image with a better quality
            settings.Density = new Density(300, 300);

            using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
            {
                log.Info(context.FunctionAppDirectory + "\\02.pdf");
                // Add all the pages of the pdf file to the collection
                images.Read(context.FunctionAppDirectory+"\\02.pdf", settings);

                int page = 1;
                foreach (MagickImage image in images)
                {
                    log.Info(context.FunctionAppDirectory + "\\outpng" + page + ".png");
                    // Write page to file that contains the page number
                    image.Write(context.FunctionAppDirectory + "\\outpng" + page + ".png");
                    // Writing to a specific format works the same as for a single image
                    //image.Format = MagickFormat.Ptif;
                    //image.Write(SampleFiles.OutputDirectory + "Snakeware.Page" + page + ".tif");
                    page++;
                }
            }

            log.Info("convert finish");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the result pic in azure.

[image]

Comment: If this could help you, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: I tried your solution but stuck at this **ImageMagick.MagickDelegateErrorException: 'FailedToExecuteCommand `"gswin32c.exe" **

Comment: I got this error ever, after re-upload the gsdll32.dll file, re-publish and restart the app then it works, suppose It's because the gsdll32.dl is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions runs inside a secure environment, aka a sandbox. There are quite some limitations to this sandbox, all of them are described here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox

In your specific case you are limited because the process does not have access to GDI32 as is mentioned on the page linked above:

> For the sake of radical attack surface area reduction, the sandbox
>   prevents almost all of the Win32k.sys APIs from being called, which
>   practically means that most of User32/GDI32 system calls are blocked.
>   For most applications this is not an issue since most Azure Web Apps
>   do not require access to Windows UI functionality (they are web
>   applications after all).
>
> There are multiple libraries used to convert HTML to PDF. Many
>   Windows/.NET specific versions leverage IE APIs and therefore leverage
>   User32/GDI32 extensively. These APIs are largely blocked in the
>   sandbox (regardless of plan) and therefore these frameworks do not
>   work in the sandbox.
>
> There are some frameworks that do not leverage User32/GDI32
>   extensively (wkhtmltopdf, for example) and we are working on enabling
>   these in Basic+ the same way we enabled SQL Reporting.

You probably need to find an alternative way to create PDF files or move the compute outside of Azure Functions.

Comment: 1. If this is the limitation than why I get error once in 5 times of execution. 2. Also, after deploying code in azure, I did load testing and it throws COM exception with different codes 0x80070040, 0x800704CD, Is that because of this limitation ? Does it happen when continuous requests are performed ?